# Retrofit Interceptor not adding query param to URL

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to add apikey in the URL using custom `interceptor` but it's not adding the params in the URL so response body is null.

**CustomInterceptor**

```
class CustomInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        val url = chain.request().url().newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("apiKey", API_KEY)
            .build()

        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
class Client {

    companion object {

        const val API_KEY = "123123"
        private const val apiUrl = "https://www.omdbapi.com/"

        fun <T> create(service: Class<T>): T {
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(CustomInterceptor())
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build()
                .create(service)
        }
    }
}
```

**IMovie**

```
interface IMovie {

    @GET("/")
    fun searchMovie(@Query("s") query: String): Call<SearchResult>
}
```

After sending the request the response body is null and this is the

*Actual URL:- [https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Man](https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Man_)*

*Expected URL:- [https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Man&apikey=123123](https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Man&apikey=123123_)*

Comment: Why not just `val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("apiKey", API_KEY)
            .build()` ? Why two builders?

Comment: Umm.. it's not working as you suggested.

Comment: I have only added headers through an interceptor, not query parameters. It is possible that Retrofit simply ignores any pre-established query parameters. You might check the Retrofit issue tracker to see if there has been any discussion about this sort of thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare So how should I add this `apikey` in every request?

Comment: You might check the Retrofit issue tracker to see if there has been any discussion about this sort of thing. I have only ever added query parameters via `@Query` annotations, such as the `s` parameter from your code.

Comment: `val request = chain.request().newBuilder() .addQueryParameter("apiKey", API_KEY) .build()` is showing error on `.addQueryParameter`

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong -- your first builder is an `HttpUrl.Builder`, not a `Request.Builder`. My apologies for that mistake. That reinforces my guess that Retrofit is simply ignoring any query parameters supplied on the request URL.

Comment: It's fine! @CommonsWare

Comment: @VarunRaj I copied your code and that's what my local web server got: `127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2019 16:07:12] "GET /?s=man&apiKey=123456`, so it seems like both query arguments are correctly retained. FYI I'm using Retrofit v2.6.1

Comment: @user2340612 did you try logging out in your android app?

Comment: @VarunRaj not really, I created a simple program targeting the JVM and in debug I could see that both the query arguments were retained, as confirmed by the local web server

Comment: @user2340612 Well in the app I made when doing this `Log.e("url", call.request().url().toString())` inside the `onResponse` function I'm getting the URL posted above.

Comment: @VarunRaj what version of retrofit/okhttp are you using? Maybe it was a bug in a previous version

Comment: @user2340612 this line `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'`

Comment: @VarunRaj I tried also with that version and it's still working for me. I didn't try it on Android as it's not set up on my machine, but on JVM I couldn't reproduce your problem

Comment: What are you seeing/experiencing that makes you say the parameter is not added?

Answer (score 1):

First create a new httpUrl instance from the existing request adding your query parameter and value:

`var request = chain.request()`

`val httpUrl = request.url().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("token", authToken).build()`

Then update the request:

`request = request.newBuilder().url(httpUrl).build()`

and proceed with it:

`return chain.proceed(request)`

- When you recall the request from the chain (the one you proceed with after manipulation) you are getting the unmodified request again.

Comment: It worked when I updated the version. But still, when I log out the URL it's showing the same URL.